# Python Regex findall But Not Including the conditional string

Tags: python, regex, findall

i have this string:

`The quick red fox jumped over the lazy brown dog lazy`

And i wrote this regex which gives me this:

```
s = The quick red fox jumped over the lazy brown dog lazy

re.findall(r'[\s\w\S]*?(?=lazy)', ss)
```

which gives me below output:

`['The quick red fox jumped over the ', '', 'azy brown dog ', '']`

But i am trying to get the output like this:

`['The quick red fox jumped over the ']`

Which means the regex should give me everything till it encounters the first `lazy` instead of last one and i only want to use `findall`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make the pattern *non-greedy* by adding a `?`:

```
>>> m = re.search(r'[\s\w\S]*?(?=lazy)', s)
#                            ^
>>> m.group()
'The quick red fox jumped over the '
```

Comment: I want to use `findall`. Can you suggest how to write this according to `findall`

Comment: @nikunj2512 `re.findall(r'[\s\w\S]*?(?=lazy)', s)[0]`